# Lottie Animation is malfunctioning

Tags: java, android, lottie

i have a lottie animation, everything looks good but as soon as the animation starts the whole screen starts to turn white

XML

```
<com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
                android:id="@+id/progressBar"
                android:layout_width="100dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
                app:lottie_loop="true"
                android:background="@drawable/background"
                app:lottie_rawRes="@raw/insights" />
```

JSON File

```
{"v":"5.4.4","fr":60,"ip":0,"op":240,"w":600,"h":600,"nm":"INSIGHTS","ddd":0,"assets":[],"layers":[{"ddd":0,"ind":1,"ty":4,"nm":"INSIGHTS ICON/Analyzer-Splash-Icons Outlines","sr":1,"ks":{"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":11},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":10},"p":{"a":0,"k":[300,300,0],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[155.5,106.5,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833,0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167,0.167]},"t":53,"s":[100,100,100],"e":[100,100,100]},{"t":57}],"ix":6}},"ao":0,"ef":[{"ty":25,"nm":"Drop Shadow","np":8,"mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow","ix":1,"en":1,"ef":[{"ty":2,"nm":"Shadow Color","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0001","ix":1,"v":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":1}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Opacity","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0002","ix":2,"v":{"a":0,"k":127.5,"ix":2}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Direction","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0003","ix":3,"v":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Distance","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0004","ix":4,"v":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4}},{"ty":0,"nm":"Softness","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0005","ix":5,"v":{"a":0,"k":27,"ix":5}},{"ty":7,"nm":"Shadow Only","mn":"ADBE Drop Shadow-0006","ix":6,"v":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6}}]}],"shapes":[{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[0,-28.051],[28.171,0],[0,28.051],[-28.164,0]],"o":[[0,28.051],[-28.164,0],[0,-28.051],[28.171,0]],"v":[[51,0],[-0.002,50.79],[-51,0],[-0.002,-50.79]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":5,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":10,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[155.5,105.29],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":0,"k":[100,100],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 1","np":2,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":1,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"gr","it":[{"ind":0,"ty":"sh","ix":1,"ks":{"a":0,"k":{"i":[[63.742,0],[33.085,-62.728],[-63.737,0],[-33.091,62.722]],"o":[[-63.737,0],[33.085,62.722],[63.742,0],[-33.091,-62.728]],"v":[[-0.003,-104],[-153,0],[-0.003,104],[153,0]],"c":true},"ix":2},"nm":"Path 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Shape - Group","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[1,1,1,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":5,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":10,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 2","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"st","c":{"a":0,"k":[0.349000010771,0.352999997606,0.365000017952,1],"ix":3},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":4},"w":{"a":0,"k":1,"ix":5},"lc":2,"lj":1,"ml":10,"bm":0,"nm":"Stroke 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Graphic - Stroke","hd":false},{"ty":"tr","p":{"a":0,"k":[155.5,106.5],"ix":2},"a":{"a":0,"k":[0,0],"ix":1},"s":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167]},"t":53,"s":[100,100],"e":[100,3]},{"i":{"x":[0.833,0.833],"y":[0.833,0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167,0.167],"y":[0.167,0.167]},"t":55,"s":[100,3],"e":[100,100]},{"t":57}],"ix":3},"r":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":6},"o":{"a":0,"k":100,"ix":7},"sk":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":4},"sa":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":5},"nm":"Transform"}],"nm":"Group 2","np":3,"cix":2,"bm":0,"ix":2,"mn":"ADBE Vector Group","hd":false},{"ty":"tm","s":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":1},"e":{"a":1,"k":[{"i":{"x":[0.833],"y":[0.833]},"o":{"x":[0.167],"y":[0.167]},"t":0,"s":[0],"e":[100]},{"t":37}],"ix":2},"o":{"a":0,"k":0,"ix":3},"m":1,"ix":3,"nm":"Trim Paths 1","mn":"ADBE Vector Filter - Trim","hd":false}],"ip":0,"op":120,"st":0,"bm":0}],"markers":[]}
```

Comment: It may be related to some features that are not supported in the version on android you are using. you can see Logcat and filter the word Lottie to see what is the rendering issue

Comment: Nothing is found as a result of logcat